# Как удалить все триггеры из таблицы?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Нужно сделать процедуру, которая будет удалять триггеры.
Вариант 1.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE sym_drop_cur_triggers (IN database_name VARCHAR(255), table_name VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
 DECLARE trigger_to_rm VARCHAR(255);
 DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t.TRIGGER_NAME from information_schema.TRIGGERS t 
 WHERE t.TRIGGER_SCHEMA = database_name
  AND t.EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = table_name;

 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

 OPEN cur1;
  REPEAT
  FETCH cur1 INTO trigger_to_rm;
  IF NOT done THEN
   -- remove curent trigers
   IF lower(trigger_to_rm) LIKE 'sym_%' THEN
    set @rmquery = concat('DROP TRIGGER ', database_name, '.' , trigger_to_rm);
    PREPARE STMT FROM @rmquery;
    EXECUTE STMT;
   END IF;
  END IF;

 UNTIL done END REPEAT;
 CLOSE cur1;

 END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Но MySQL не поддеживаетя  такое.
Error Code: 1295. This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Вариант 2

```
SELECT CONCAT(database_name, '.' ,TRIGGER_NAME) INTO trigger_name_for_db  
    FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS WHERE TRIGGER_SCHEMA = database_name 
        AND EVENT_OBJECT_TABLE = table_name ;


DROP TRIGGER   trigger_name_for_db;
```

Но переменные не подставляются для drop table нужна именно строка, ошибка:

Trigger not exists.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE new_name AS old_name;` `INSERT INTO new_name SELECT * FROM old_name;` `DROP TABLE old_name;` `RENAME TABLE new_name TO oldName;`

Comment: На сервере каждый день происходит архивация таблиц с которых я и удаляю триггеры, копировать все данные возможно слишком тяжело для бд.

Comment: Не понял... поподробнее... Архивация - это типа бэкап делается? как, чем? триггеры можно и не бэкапить, на это у стандартных программ ключик специальный есть.

Comment: create table myDb.users_new like myDb.users;
rename table myDb.users to myDb.users_old;
rename table myDb.users_new to myDb.users;
Вот и вся архивация ;)

Comment: Збс... но на новой таблице триггеров никаких не будет - откуда же они берутся к моменту следующей "архивации"?

Comment: Они есть на старой, и мне нужно что бы они были на новой. Создать их на новой не проблема. Но сначала нужно удалить на старой.

Comment: *Создать их на новой не проблема. Но сначала нужно удалить на старой.* ну раз "создать не проблема" - значит, имеется их список. Тогда какая проблема в пару к скрипту, создающему триггеры, сделать и скрипт, их удаляющий?

Comment: Возможное автоматизированное решение. Формируем набор запросов на DROP TRIGGER, как сделано - но получаем одним селектом (используя строковые функции) сразу все, по одному запросу на одно поле записи. И... вываливаем это в файл (SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE). Ну а потом выполняем извне этот файл тупым `mysql < созданный_файл`.

Comment: Их создает автоматически SymmetricDS, имена могут измениться поэтому напрямую прописать никак.

Comment: А можно это фаил из процедуры выполнить?

Comment: Нет. Только клиентом (команда SOURCE - это не SQL). Из процедуры - это prepared statement, а это ты уже проходил...

Comment: Спасибо,  буду медитировать)